# Error bar on slopes of linear regression

Tags: regression

For a specific project I needed to determine a parameter from the slope on a line based on inputs and output ($Y = mX + b;$ sorry, can't get too specific). To estimate the error on that parameter, I did some google searches and found the following

$errorbar_{m} = m \times t_{\alpha/2} \times \sqrt{ \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{r.sq} -1 }{n - 2}}$

$ m = m_{estimate} \pm errorbar_m$

with $t_{\alpha/2}$ being the appropriate t parameter, `r.sq` the Pearson correlation coefficient r squared, and `n-2` the degrees of freedom based on number of data points.

Of course, I forgot where I found this and later I needed this again. I only found the textbook expressions based on

$ m  = m_{estimate} \pm t_{\alpha/2}\,\dfrac{s}{ \sqrt{S_{xx}}}.$

Question 1. Where does the formula involving `1/r.sq - 1`come from? Is it even valid?

Question 2. Does anyone have a reference to the formula?

Comment: It is difficult to give any credence to your first formula, because when $m=0$ it gives no error, which obviously is wrong.  Why not [look up the formula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+standard+error+slope) so you can get it right?  That would likely clarify things for you and, even if not, will lead to simpler answers.

Comment: I completely agree with your assessment at m = 0, but I did some recalculation on my data where m <> 0 and came out with this:

```
err.bar      err.bar.regular
    <dbl>           <dbl>
1   3.09            3.09
2   8.06            8.06
3   0.954           0.954
4   0.374           0.374
```
(bad formatting, but numbers are equal)